# Can the song image be gotten faster?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I'm working on music player that displays all the songs and images of respective songs from a local device on a fragment.

When i launch the app it takes a long time to load i noticed it was the **getImagesForSongs()** that was slow in processing

why is it slow? and is there a better way and how can i do it?

**My All Song fragment class**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.mikeinvents.musicbaze.R;
import com.mikeinvents.musicbaze.adapters.SongAdapter;
import com.mikeinvents.musicbaze.data_model.SongModel;
import com.mikeinvents.musicbaze.ui.MainActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AllSongsFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<SongModel> song;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever;
    static byte[] rawArt;
   static Bitmap art;
   static BitmapFactory.Options bfo;

    public AllSongsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_songs, container, false);
       // setRetainInstance(true);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.song_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void loadSongList() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver();


        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC;
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri,null,selection,null,sortOrder);

        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            song = new ArrayList<>();

            //get columns
            do {
                String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String timeDuration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));

                //convert time
                int duration = Integer.parseInt(timeDuration);
                @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String time = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) -
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                                .toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)));
                //save to list
                song.add(new SongModel(data, title, artist, album, time));

                Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, " Added: "+"data = "+data+" title = "+title+
                        " album = "+album+" artist: "+artist+" duration = "+time);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        if(cursor !=null){
            cursor.close();
        }

    }

    private void getImagesForSongs(){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver();


        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC;
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri,null,selection,null,sortOrder);

        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
            do{
                String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));


                //get song image
                mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(data);
                Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Data source has been set");

                rawArt = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
                Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Raw art has been gotten");

                bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                art = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(100,100);


                //save to list
                bitmaps.add(art);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }

    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 4;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.

            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"Calculated in sample size");

        return inSampleSize;
    }


    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        bfo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        if(rawArt != null){
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt,0,rawArt.length,bfo);
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Gotten embedded picture");
            // Calculate inSampleSize
            calculateInSampleSize(bfo,reqWidth,reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            bfo.inJustDecodeBounds = false;


            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt,0,rawArt.length,bfo);
        }

        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Gotten null embedded picture");

        return null;

    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        ProgressDialog pd;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            pd.setTitle("Please wait...");
            pd.setMessage("Fetching songs");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            getImagesForSongs();
            loadSongList();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pd.dismiss();
            SongAdapter songAdapter = new SongAdapter(getContext(), song, bitmaps);
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"Initialized adapter");
            recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter);
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"Adapter has been set");

        }
    }

}
```

**My SongAdapter class**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.mikeinvents.musicbaze.R;
import com.mikeinvents.musicbaze.data_model.SongModel;
import com.mikeinvents.musicbaze.ui.MainActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SongAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context ctx;
    private ArrayList<SongModel> mSong;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> mBitmap;

    public SongAdapter(Context ct, ArrayList<SongModel> song, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap){
        ctx = ct;
        mSong = song;
        mBitmap = bitmap;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SongAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_row,viewGroup,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SongAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        SongModel song = mSong.get(i);
        viewHolder.songTitle.setText(song.getTitle());
        viewHolder.songArtist.setText(song.getArtist());
        viewHolder.songAlbum.setText(song.getAlbum());
        viewHolder.songTime.setText(song.getSongTime());
       // Glide.with(ctx).load(mBitmap.get(i)).fallback(R.drawable.mojo_logo).into(viewHolder.songImage);

        if(mBitmap.get(i) == null){
            viewHolder.songImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.mojo_logo);
        }else if(mBitmap.get(i) !=null){
            viewHolder.songImage.setImageBitmap(mBitmap.get(i));
        }




        viewHolder.moreOptions.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(ctx,v);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.more_options_action_share:
                        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Implement Share Option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.more_options_action_add_fav:
                        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Implement Favorite Option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.more_options_action_delete:
                        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Implement Delete Option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }

            });

            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.more_options_popup);
            popupMenu.show();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSong.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView songImage, moreOptions;
        TextView songTitle, songArtist, songAlbum, songTime;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            songImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_row_song_image);
            moreOptions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_row_more_options);
            songTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_row_name_of_song);
            songArtist = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_row_artist_name);
            songAlbum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_row_album_name);
            songTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_row_song_time);

            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"Views in song_row layout initialized");
        }

    }


}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you fetching the songs images?

Comment: From the local device

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a concrete fix, but there are some things that could be done to speed up the loading.

bitmap can be slow, so if it is possible to get png images instead this would speed up the process. in the decodeSampledBitmapFromResource method, you run

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt,0,rawArt.length,bfo);
```

twice, which seems unessecary, but perhaps im missing something.

additionally you could lazyload images instead of loading all images for every song at once, you can fetch the image in onBindViewHolder. this way every image will also be fetched asynchronously in paralell.

Comment: Thanks but somewhat confusing to me.

Comment: `additionally you could lazyload images` Yes. Thats how it should be done.